# Query or log all query with invalid object name error

Tags: sql-server, error-log, invalid-object-name

I have got an old and big database with a lot of extra stored procedures. I've executed a query to find unused queries.

```
SELECT 
  O.name,
  PS.last_execution_time
FROM 
  sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats PS 
INNER JOIN sys.objects O 
  ON O.[object_id] = PS.[object_id]
```

I found about 2000 unused store procedures. Sql server uptime is about one month. I'm not sure all of this sp's are unused. so I want to find a solution to monitor database after drop this store procedures. I want to know is there a way to query all 'Invalid object name' errors that raise after this big change. I'll appreciate your helps.

Comment: Use XEvents to monitor for errors with a filter for error number 208

Comment: Thank you so much. I found this item in "error_reported" event. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, you probably want to add a filter `WHERE (error_number = 208)`